# Unknown detail about mean R.V.,normal variance

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, variance, means

How can I see that for a $N(\mu_0,\sigma^2)$  R.V.  $X_1,...,X_n$ this

$$
Z =\frac{\bar{X} - \mu_0}{\sigma / \sqrt{n}}
$$

has a standard $N(0,1)$, and **not** this:

$$
Z =\frac{\bar{X} - \mu_0}{\sigma^2 /{n}}
$$?

Comment: Calculate both variances… the first one hast variance 1, the second one $\frac{1}{\sigma^2}$

Comment: If I were able to calculate them I wouldn't ask.How can I see that they are 1 and $\frac{1}{\sigma^2}$?

Comment: What's your problem with calculating them? Without pointing that out one cannot help you. All you need is $$\text{Var}(aX) = a^2\text{Var}(X) \\ \text{Var}(X + c) = \text{Var}(X)$$ and $$\text{Var}(X+Y) = \text{Var}(X) + \text{Var}(Y)$$ for independent r.v. $X,Y$ and $c\in\Bbb R$ what should be known calculation rules for the variance.

Comment: And why isn't that second one $\frac{1}{n \sigma^2}$ but $\frac{1}{\sigma^2}$?

Comment: Actually the second one has variance $\frac{n}{\sigma^2}$… just missed the n :-)

Comment: OK then..........!    :-)

Comment: Got it? Question answered?

Comment: I understand but I cannot compute it. Would you try how variances 1 and $\frac{n}{\sigma^2}$ were obtained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ independent then you have $$\overline{X} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$$ and so it follows $$\text{Var}(\overline{X}) = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n \text{Var}(X_k) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}$$
and we get

$$\text{Var}\left(\frac{\overline{X} - \mu_0}{\sigma / \sqrt{n}}\right) = \frac{n}{\sigma^2}\text{Var}(\overline{X}) = \frac{n}{\sigma^2}\frac{\sigma^2}{n} = 1$$
as well as 
$$\text{Var}\left(\frac{\overline{X} - \mu_0}{\sigma^2 / n}\right) = \frac{n^2}{\sigma^4}\text{Var}(\overline{X}) = \frac{n^2}{\sigma^4}\frac{\sigma^2}{n} = \frac{n}{\sigma^2}$$

Comment: Thank you, it's pretty clear now. I'm sorry that you have to do so much writing.